# An upper-bound for variance of a random variable satisfying a linear inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be a vector of $m$ correlated non-negative random variables satisfying the following inequality
$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\leq\mathbf{1},$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a $n\times m$ random matrix. Is there any upper-bound for the variance of elements of $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: I think more conditions are needed.  Consider $A = [1, 0; 0, -1]$, $x_1  \sim N(0,\sigma)$ and $x_2 = -x_1$.  The inequality always holds but the variance of each coordinate can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: You are correct. Random variables are non-negative.